# External monitor ubuntu 13.04 for NVIDI quadro 1000M on W530

Tags: nvidia

I have just got a thinkpad W530 with NIVIDIA quadro 1000M graphic and I cannot connect an external monitor properly. It shows up on ubuntu 13.04 but it seems there might be a problem with the driver since my mouse cursor keeps blinking when I change the display setting to the twin view.
Do you know how I can have it worked?
Cheers,
Kia

Answer (score 0):

My W520 has the same graphics card. I am using RHEL 6.4 so hopefully the solution is the same. You have to enter the BIOS and select discreet graphics only. Then make sure you are using the latest proprietary drivers available. Once the proprietary drivers are installed you will need to enable twinview. For more information on twinview please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have at least "50 reputations" I am not able to add a comment to the answer ob "Rob".

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad w520 with nVidia quadro 1000m

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 and NVidia 375 propriety driver. "prime-nvidia" is also installed (automatically when I installed the nVidia-closed-source-drivers)

His hint worked for me. Go to BIOS and define "descrete graphics".

After that I had done the following things:

- Install closed source drivers (version 375 ist my current one).
- root> prime-select nvidia
- delete the /etc/X11/xorg.conf - file
- create an empty config file using

  - root> nvidia-xconfig
- reboot
- login into X (KDE)
- in a terminal run "sudo nvidia-settings"
- Left pane find "X Server Display Configuration", click it
- Right pane find both Displays (internal LCD and via Displayport connected external LCD)
- "configure the displays as you want them" (position, etc)
- click "apply"
- click "Save to X Configuration File"
- (maybe: logoff and login again, I forgot)

Thats all. Now I have both displays next to each other.

"TwinView" and "Xinerama" seems not to be installed on my system. Both screens are belonging to "Configuration: X screeen 0". So I have a screen over both displays :-)